# tkinter window doesn't load correctly after first file run in Spyder

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, error-handling, kernel

So far I have tried the advice from u/OA998

"""https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/45h05k/solved_kernel_crashing_when_closing_gui_spyder/

My code is supposed to just open up a window with two labels and an entry field. The code works fine if I restart the Kernel but just running it after closing the window will result in an window popping up that has no text (from the StringVar). The third time it doesn't even open anymore. I'm not quite sure what causes this."""

Code:

""" create a GUI inside a class (this allows variables to be added and changed by several parts in the GUI). By using the “self” keyword we can access the attributes and methods of the class in python. It binds the attributes with the given arguments.

```
from tkinter import *
```

""" create a GUI inside a class (this allows variables to be added and changed by several parts in the GUI)"""
""" By using the “self” keyword we can access the attributes and methods of the class in python. It binds the attributes with the given arguments."""

```
class TESTGUI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        
        """We will use an entry widget, and StringVar to keep track of the current text in the
        box, and a label to display a message."""
        
        """labelpositioning"""
        
        margin = 2
        
        self.spacer = Label(window, width=margin, height=margin)
        self.spacer.grid(column=0,row=0)
        
        """for toogle button create StringVar in tkinter class to hold the text"""
        
        """labeltexts"""
        
        self.labelText_1 = StringVar()
        self.labelText_1.set("begin experiment")
        
        self.labelText_2 = StringVar()
        self.labelText_2.set("calibrate")
        
        """labelformat"""
        
        self.label = Label(window, textvariable=self.labelText_1, width=12, height=3, borderwidth=3, relief=SOLID)
        self.label.grid(column=1, row=1)
        
        self.label = Label(window, textvariable=self.labelText_2, width=12, height=3, borderwidth=3, relief=SOLID)
        self.label.grid(column=2, row=1)

        """labelbutton"""
        
        self.button = Button(window, text="press", command=self.pressed_button_1)
        self.button.grid(column=1,row=2)
        
        self.button = Button(window, text="press", command=self.pressed_button_2)
        self.button.grid(column=2,row=2)
        
        """Entry(password)Label"""
        
        self.entryLabel_1 = Label(window, text = "enter your password")
        self.entryLabel_1.grid(column=0,row=3)
        
        """ Next add a StringVar to hold the password and Entry box to type the password."""
        """ The trace function will call a checkStrength() function when the StringVar is changed."""
        
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.password.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, password=self.password:self.checkStrenght())
        
        self.entry = Entry(window, textvariable=self.password)
        self.entry.grid(column=1, row=3)
        
        """ then create the StringVar to hold the strength string, and the label to display it. """
        
        self.strenghtText = StringVar()
        self.strenghtText.set("")
        
        self.strenghtLabel = Label(window, textvariable=self.strenghtText, width=10)
        self.strenghtLabel.grid(column=3, row=3)
        
        """CheckStrenghtFunctionOfEntry"""
        
    def checkStrenght(self):
        lenght = len(self.password.get())
        if lenght == 0:
            self.strenghtText.set("")
            self.strenghtLabel.config(bg="SystemWindowBody")
        elif lenght >= 1:
            self.strenghtText.set("strong")
            self.strenghtText.config(bg = "green3")
            
        """ButtonFunction"""
        
    def pressed_button_1(self):
        if self.labelText_1.get() == "begin experiment":
            self.labelText_1.set("abort experiment")
        else:
            self.labelText_1.set("begin experiment")
            
    def pressed_button_2(self):
        if self.labelText_2.get() == "calibrate":
            self.labelText_2.set("recalibrate")
        else:
            self.labelText_2.set("calibrate")
            


    
    
            
        
""" define Variables for window size """

width=300
height=300

"""  define tk for used variable to use tkinter class """



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    window = Tk()
    window.minsize(width, height)
    window.title("Photonics Lab")

    gui = TESTGUI(window)

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Edit. Add screenshot.

> A variable defined using `StringVar()` holds a string data where we can
> set text value and can retrieve it. Also, we can pass this variable to
> `textvariable` parameter for a widget like `Entry`, `Label`, `Text`.

In line 74, Change this :

```
self.strenghtText.config(bg = "green")
```

to:

```
self.strenghtLabel.config(bg = "green")
```

Btw, Those two buttons worked  fine.

Screenshot:

[image]